# How to fix 'Connection aborted.' error in Python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, disconnect

I had been running this code daily for weeks with no error. This morning, it ran the `for` loop over 100 times properly, then gave a connection issue. Each time I have tried to run it since, it will run anywhere from 5 to 130 times, but always gives the connection error before completing.

I am still getting status codes of 200. I've seen some posts referencing 'memory leak' issues in Python, but I'm not sure how to figure out if that's the problem here. It's also strange because it had been working fine until today.

I have similar code for other pages on the same site that still runs correctly all the way through.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

updates = []

print(f'Getting {total_timebanks} timebank details... ')
for timebank in range(len(timebanks)):
    url = f"http://community.timebanks.org/{timebanks['slug'][timebank]}"
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')

    update = {}
    update['members'] = soup.find('div', {'class': 'views-field-field-num-users-value'}).span.text.strip().replace(',', '')

    updates.append(update)

    time.sleep(1)
```

And here is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RemoteDisconnected                        Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    265             # sending a valid response.
--> 266             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    267                                      " response")

RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ProtocolError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    366             if read is False or not self._is_method_retryable(method):
--> 367                 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
    368             elif read is not None:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    684         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 685             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    686         raise value

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    383                     # otherwise it looks like a programming error was the cause.
--> 384                     six.raise_from(e, None)
    385         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError, SocketError) as e:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    379                 try:
--> 380                     httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
    381                 except Exception as e:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in getresponse(self)
   1330             try:
-> 1331                 response.begin()
   1332             except ConnectionError:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in begin(self)
    296         while True:
--> 297             version, status, reason = self._read_status()
    298             if status != CONTINUE:

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py in _read_status(self)
    265             # sending a valid response.
--> 266             raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
    267                                      " response")

ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-31257fee2c23> in <module>
      5 for timebank in range(len(timebanks)):
      6     url = f"http://community.timebanks.org/{timebanks['slug'][timebank]}"
----> 7     res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
      8     soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'lxml')
      9 

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     73 
     74     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 75     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     76 
     77 

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     58     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 
     62 

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    531         }
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 
    535         return resp

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    644 
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 
    648         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/anaconda3/envs/DSI-6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    496 
    497         except (ProtocolError, socket.error) as err:
--> 498             raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    499 
    500         except MaxRetryError as e:

ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

Comment: It could just be that the website owners are limiting the number of allowed accesses (total count, or rate per minutes or other interval)...

Comment: A solution would be to use a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to have resolved itself. With no changes to the code, it is back to running as expected this morning.

I don't have much insight as to why I had connection errors yesterday, but it does seem to have been an issue with the site, not the code.

Thanks for the responses! For reference, I had also tried increasing sleep timer to 30, but that did not resolve the problem yesterday.